# how to communicate from one directive to another directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have tow directives one is for ng-grid another is for pagination when I click page numbers in one directive ng-grid directive should be changed according to that, can I have any idea on that.

Comment: can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Use `$scope.$broadcast`, `$scope.$emit` or `$rootScope.$broadcast` depending on your situation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it:
For example:

**First solution**

You can share data between directives:

```
<directive-one attribute="value" other-attribute="value2" shared-variable="yourData">
<directive-two shared-variable="yourData">
```

And set `$watch` inside first directive on that value

```
scope.$watch('yourData',function(newVal,oldVal){ //your logic called after change });
```

**Second solution**

You can use events:

```
app.directive('first',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'Im first directive!',
        scope: true,
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
            scope.$on('event',function(event,args){
               alert(args); 
            });
        }
    }    
});

app.directive('second',function($rootScope){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'Im second directive! <button ng-click="click()">click me!</button>',
        scope: true,
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
            scope.click = function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('event','hello!');    
            };

        }
    }    
});
```

Event is sent by `$rootScope.$broadcast('event','hello!');`. It means event is sent by your root scope downwards to child scopes. http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/fJs69/

Comment: @PSL Ok, i'm changing it ;)